# disable closing or minimising of a win form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have searched but cannot find a solution to my problem

I am wanting to develop a c# based windows form application that will be used as a homemade taskbar on a touchscreen pc monitor.

is there a way to remove the minimize/window scale and close button from the top of a winform?

Also is there a way to ensure that the window stay on top at all times, as the start button/taskbar/system tray does by default in windows?

thanks for any and all help.

Comment: `FormBorderStyle = None`, `TopMost = true`. button/taskbar/system tray don't stay on top of everything, just on top of the z-order. See also the [Windows.UI.Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications) namespace (more *modern* stuff)

Comment: Btw, a User can always use TaskManager to close an application. You can do nothing to prevent it (except fill the screen and try to hide/close Task Manager when a User opens it, but that's malware).

Comment: Google "windows forms shappbarmessage" to find out how to do this right.

Answer (score 1):

Jimi is correct, I would just add the maximized option if you want a true full screen app 
Add this to your Form_Load to test it:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.TopLevel = true;
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this from visual side : Go to your form designer, right click on that and click on `Properties`.

Set these values :

`WindowState : Maximized`

`TopMost : True`

`FormBorderStyle : None`

And if you want to set those from Designer code use **@Weronnie 's Answer** :

> `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` 
>   `this.TopLevel = true;`
>   `this.TopMost = true;`
>   `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`